# Termination letter marked 1 day early

Tags: health-insurance, indiana

Someone I know was let go from their job on 4/1, he was using the insurance provided by his  employer. In his employment contract it states insurance will remain active through the rest of the month he was let go in. Despite calling him in on 4/1 (normally his day off) to let him go, the termination letter he was given stated he was let go on 3/31.

This is relevant now because he is looking at getting insurance through COBRA, but because his company sponsored insurance plan ended on 3/31 he would have to pay the COBRA premium for both April and May.

My question is: Is it legal for his employer to mark his termination date as 3/31 when they let him go on 4/1?

Comment: Was he terminated on 3/31 and notified the next day? That is, what is the evidence that he *wasn't* terminated on 3/31?

Comment: Was he an hourly employee or on salary?  Was it legal for them to call him into the office on April 1st without paying him?  Alternatively, if they did pay him, then they cannot claim that he was terminated the day before.

Comment: I wonder whether even directing him to appear in the office on April 1st implies that his termination date cannot be earlier, regardless of whether he was paid.  Was he in fact directed to appear or merely asked?

Comment: @phoog He was a salaried employee. He was also told he must come in on 4/1, it wasn't a question.

Comment: @user6726 I'm not quite sure how to answer that. According to the paperwork he was terminated on 3/31, but he was called in on 4/1 to be told about it. So until the morning of 4/1 he believed he was still employed

Comment: His personal believes aren't what define the situation, the actions of the employer do. There doesn't seem to be any statute / regulation covering this, but perhaps there's a common law construction that addresses the issue, having to do with the contractual right to be provided insurance. Requiring him to appear on 4-1 is strong evidence that the employer was treating him as an employee, but no doubt there will be a dispute as to what they actually said.